# Android: How to create bed design in xml?

Tags: android, android-animation

[image: beddesign]

Actually i am able to create this design by using `RotateAnimation` but getting problem when i want to change it and applying any animation.We know, `Animation` does not alter the actual properties of the View, it only animates it. So every time i am facing the **issue** like :

> animation get back to its real state after finishing the animation and
>   start every time from initial position.

So to avoid this i want to apply static design in xml . I tried using `android:rotation` but not getting as per the exact requirement. 
suggestions and helps will be mostly appreciable. Please suggest.

Comment: just add `android:fillAfter="true"` in animation(xml) or in java code.

Comment: I tried with that also but not able to avoid recreation of animation :(

Comment: I am facing same problem? please anybody get rid this.

Comment: You mean you tried using `android:rotation` in onAnimationEnd? Can you show how did you try with `android:rotation`?

Answer (score 0):

I know `android:fillAfter="true"` causes many problems!

Another option would be you could add animation listeners to the animation and once that animation finished, you manually set final transfomrations to the views.

```
yourAnimation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        /* Here, you could set them manually */
    }

    @Override
    public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {

    }
});
```

Comment: @#abforce thanks.  I all ready use this but in onAnimationEnd() i am unable to hide the view .. any suggestions ??

Comment: @SubhalaxmiNayak _"i am unable to hide the view"_... What do you mean? hiding a view is simple. `view.setVisibility(View.GONE)`